# Simple C++ Hash library and its abstraction, Design that seems out of focus?

Tags: c++

First Question:
[Simple C++ Hash function library](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/250149/simple-c-hash-function-library)

> I had created hash function library (`MD5`, `MD4`, `SHA256`, `SHA384`, `SHA512`, `RipeMD128`, `RipeMD160`, `CRC16`, `CRC32`, `CRC64`), written in C++.
> Everything working well and My library produces exactly the same output compared to the PHP output. (Except for CRC series)
> The individual algorithmic abstraction layers consist of the chash::IAlgorithm interface and chash::IDigest. But I'd like to refine IDigest more elegantly. How can I do it?
> Full code: https://github.com/whoamiho1006/chash

I had modified following `G. Sliepen`'s opinion.

1. Removal of IDigest interface.
2. Forwarded `std::vector<uint8_t>` to `CDigest`.

And then, the question arose about the need for the TAlgorithm template class. I was explicitly intent on making that interface can be deleted by the C++ `delete` keyword. However, there is a strong feeling of something awkward and a little heavy.

The reason for designing this class was to make the implementation of the IAlgorithm interface short and reliable, but it feels like something is out of focus. Should I keep this class? Or should it be removed and redesigned?

**Modified IAlgorithm class**

```
#pragma once
#include "Macros.hpp"
#include <vector>

namespace chash {
    enum class EAlgorithm {
        Unknown     = 0x0000,
        CRC16       = 0x1000,       // --> IBM Poly-Nomial.
        CRC32       = 0x1001,       // --> IEEE 802.3
        CRC64       = 0x1002,       // --> ISO Poly-Nomial.
        SHA256      = 0x2000,
        SHA384      = 0x2001,
        SHA512      = 0x2002,
        MD5         = 0x3000,
        MD4         = 0x3001,
        RipeMD128   = 0x4000,
        RipeMD160   = 0x4001,
    };

    enum class EAlgorithmErrno {
        Succeed = 0,
        InvalidAlgorithm,
        InvalidState,
        //InvalidDigest
    };

    typedef std::vector<uint8_t> CDigest;

    class IAlgorithm {
    public:
        IAlgorithm(EAlgorithm type)
            : _type(type), _errno(EAlgorithmErrno::Succeed)
        { 
        }

        virtual ~IAlgorithm() { }

    private:
        EAlgorithm _type;
        EAlgorithmErrno _errno;

    protected:
        inline void setError(EAlgorithmErrno _errno) {
            this->_errno = _errno;
        }

    public:
        /* get algorithm type. */
        inline EAlgorithm type() const { return _type; }

        /* get algorithm state. */
        inline EAlgorithmErrno error() const { return _errno; }

        /* initiate the algorithm. */
        virtual bool init() = 0;

        /* update the algorithm state by given bytes. */
        virtual bool update(const uint8_t* inBytes, size_t inSize) = 0;

        /* finalize the algorithm and digest. */
        virtual bool finalize(CDigest& outDigest) = 0;
        
        /* compute hash with digest. */
        virtual EAlgorithmErrno compute(CDigest& outDigest, const uint8_t* inBytes, size_t inSize) {
            if (init()) {
                update(inBytes, inSize);
                finalize(outDigest);
            }

            return error();
        }
    };

    /* Digest to hex. */
    inline std::string toHex(const CDigest& inDigest) {
        std::string outHex;

        outHex.reserve(inDigest.size() << 1);
        for(uint8_t b : inDigest) {
            int32_t fr = b / 16;
            int32_t bk = b % 16;

            if (fr < 10) outHex.push_back('0' + fr);
            else outHex.push_back('a' + (fr - 10));

            if (bk < 10) outHex.push_back('0' + bk);
            else outHex.push_back('a' + (bk - 10));
        }

        return outHex;
    }

    /* Comparator between two CDigests. */
    inline bool operator ==(const CDigest& left, const CDigest& right) {
        if (left.size() == right.size()) {
            return !::memcmp(&left[0], &right[0], left.size());
        }

        return false;
    }


    /* Comparator between two CDigests. */
    inline bool operator !=(const CDigest& left, const CDigest& right) {
        if (left.size() == right.size()) {
            return ::memcmp(&left[0], &right[0], left.size());
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Belows are example implementation:

**CMD5.hpp**

```
#pragma once
#include "chash/IAlgorithm.hpp"

namespace chash {
    class CMD5 : public IAlgorithm {
    private:
        static const uint8_t PADDING[64];

    public:
        CMD5();
        ~CMD5() { }

    private:
        bool        _init;
        uint32_t    _state[4];
        uint64_t    _count;
        uint8_t     _buffer[64];

    public:
        bool init() override;
        bool update(const uint8_t* inBytes, size_t inSize) override;
        bool finalize(CDigest& outDigest) override;

    private:
        void updateFinal();
        void flush();
        void transform(const uint32_t* data);
    };
}
```

**CMD5.cpp**

```
#include "CMD5.hpp"

#define S11 7
#define S12 12
#define S13 17
#define S14 22
#define S21 5
#define S22 9
#define S23 14
#define S24 20
#define S31 4
#define S32 11
#define S33 16
#define S34 23
#define S41 6
#define S42 10
#define S43 15
#define S44 21

#define F(x, y, z) (((x) & (y)) | ((~x) & (z)))
#define G(x, y, z) (((x) & (z)) | ((y) & (~z)))
#define H(x, y, z) ((x) ^ (y) ^ (z))
#define I(x, y, z) ((y) ^ ((x) | (~z)))

#define ROTATE_LEFT(x, n) (((x) << (n)) | ((x) >> (32-(n))))

#define FF(a, b, c, d, x, s, ac) { \
    (a) += F ((b), (c), (d)) + (x) + ac; \
    (a) = ROTATE_LEFT ((a), (s)); \
    (a) += (b); \
}
#define GG(a, b, c, d, x, s, ac) { \
    (a) += G ((b), (c), (d)) + (x) + ac; \
    (a) = ROTATE_LEFT ((a), (s)); \
    (a) += (b); \
}
#define HH(a, b, c, d, x, s, ac) { \
    (a) += H ((b), (c), (d)) + (x) + ac; \
    (a) = ROTATE_LEFT ((a), (s)); \
    (a) += (b); \
}
#define II(a, b, c, d, x, s, ac) { \
    (a) += I ((b), (c), (d)) + (x) + ac; \
    (a) = ROTATE_LEFT ((a), (s)); \
    (a) += (b); \
}

namespace chash {
    const uint8_t CMD5::PADDING[64] = { 0x80, 0, };

    CMD5::CMD5()
        : IAlgorithm(EAlgorithm::MD5), _init(false), _count(0)
    {
    }

    bool CMD5::init()
    {
        if (_init) {
            setError(EAlgorithmErrno::InvalidState);
            return false;
        }

        _init = true;

        _state[0] = 0x67452301;
        _state[1] = 0xefcdab89;
        _state[2] = 0x98badcfe;
        _state[3] = 0x10325476;

        _count = 0;
        setError(EAlgorithmErrno::Succeed);
        return true;
    }

    bool CMD5::update(const uint8_t* inBytes, size_t inSize) {
        if (!_init) {
            setError(EAlgorithmErrno::InvalidState);
            return false;
        }

        uint32_t pos = uint32_t(_count) & 0x3f;

        while (inSize) {
            _buffer[pos++] = *inBytes++;
            _count++; inSize--;

            if (pos >= 64) {
                pos = 0;
                flush();
            }
        }

        setError(EAlgorithmErrno::Succeed);
        return true;
    }

    bool CMD5::finalize(CDigest& outDigest) {
        if (!_init) {
            setError(EAlgorithmErrno::InvalidState);
            return false;
        }

        updateFinal();
        outDigest.reserve(16);

        for (int32_t i = 0, j = 0; j < 16; ++i, j += 4) {
            outDigest.push_back(uint8_t(_state[i]));
            outDigest.push_back(uint8_t(_state[i] >> 8));
            outDigest.push_back(uint8_t(_state[i] >> 16));
            outDigest.push_back(uint8_t(_state[i] >> 24));
        }

        _init = false;
        setError(EAlgorithmErrno::Succeed);
        return true;
    }

    void CMD5::updateFinal() {
        uint8_t lenBits[8];
        uint64_t length = _count << 3;
        uint32_t index = uint32_t(_count & 0x3f),
            pads = index < 56 ? 56 - index : 120 - index;

        lenBits[0] = uint8_t(length);
        lenBits[1] = uint8_t(length >> 8);
        lenBits[2] = uint8_t(length >> 16);
        lenBits[3] = uint8_t(length >> 24);
        lenBits[4] = uint8_t(length >> 32);
        lenBits[5] = uint8_t(length >> 40);
        lenBits[6] = uint8_t(length >> 48);
        lenBits[7] = uint8_t(length >> 56);

        update(PADDING, pads);
        update(lenBits, 8);
    }

    void CMD5::flush() {
        uint32_t block[16];

        for (int32_t i = 0; i < 16; ++i) {
            block[i] =
                (uint32_t(_buffer[i * 4 + 3]) << 24) |
                (uint32_t(_buffer[i * 4 + 2]) << 16) |
                (uint32_t(_buffer[i * 4 + 1]) << 8) |
                (uint32_t(_buffer[i * 4 + 0]));
        }

        transform(block);
    }

    void CMD5::transform(const uint32_t* data) {
        uint32_t a = _state[0], b = _state[1], c = _state[2], d = _state[3];

        /* Round 1 */
        FF(a, b, c, d, data[0], S11, 0xd76aa478); /* 1 */
        FF(d, a, b, c, data[1], S12, 0xe8c7b756); /* 2 */
        FF(c, d, a, b, data[2], S13, 0x242070db); /* 3 */
        FF(b, c, d, a, data[3], S14, 0xc1bdceee); /* 4 */
        FF(a, b, c, d, data[4], S11, 0xf57c0faf); /* 5 */
        FF(d, a, b, c, data[5], S12, 0x4787c62a); /* 6 */
        FF(c, d, a, b, data[6], S13, 0xa8304613); /* 7 */
        FF(b, c, d, a, data[7], S14, 0xfd469501); /* 8 */
        FF(a, b, c, d, data[8], S11, 0x698098d8); /* 9 */
        FF(d, a, b, c, data[9], S12, 0x8b44f7af); /* 10 */
        FF(c, d, a, b, data[10], S13, 0xffff5bb1); /* 11 */
        FF(b, c, d, a, data[11], S14, 0x895cd7be); /* 12 */
        FF(a, b, c, d, data[12], S11, 0x6b901122); /* 13 */
        FF(d, a, b, c, data[13], S12, 0xfd987193); /* 14 */
        FF(c, d, a, b, data[14], S13, 0xa679438e); /* 15 */
        FF(b, c, d, a, data[15], S14, 0x49b40821); /* 16 */

        /* Round 2 */
        GG(a, b, c, d, data[1], S21, 0xf61e2562); /* 17 */
        GG(d, a, b, c, data[6], S22, 0xc040b340); /* 18 */
        GG(c, d, a, b, data[11], S23, 0x265e5a51); /* 19 */
        GG(b, c, d, a, data[0], S24, 0xe9b6c7aa); /* 20 */
        GG(a, b, c, d, data[5], S21, 0xd62f105d); /* 21 */
        GG(d, a, b, c, data[10], S22, 0x2441453); /* 22 */
        GG(c, d, a, b, data[15], S23, 0xd8a1e681); /* 23 */
        GG(b, c, d, a, data[4], S24, 0xe7d3fbc8); /* 24 */
        GG(a, b, c, d, data[9], S21, 0x21e1cde6); /* 25 */
        GG(d, a, b, c, data[14], S22, 0xc33707d6); /* 26 */
        GG(c, d, a, b, data[3], S23, 0xf4d50d87); /* 27 */
        GG(b, c, d, a, data[8], S24, 0x455a14ed); /* 28 */
        GG(a, b, c, d, data[13], S21, 0xa9e3e905); /* 29 */
        GG(d, a, b, c, data[2], S22, 0xfcefa3f8); /* 30 */
        GG(c, d, a, b, data[7], S23, 0x676f02d9); /* 31 */
        GG(b, c, d, a, data[12], S24, 0x8d2a4c8a); /* 32 */

        /* Round 3 */
        HH(a, b, c, d, data[5], S31, 0xfffa3942); /* 33 */
        HH(d, a, b, c, data[8], S32, 0x8771f681); /* 34 */
        HH(c, d, a, b, data[11], S33, 0x6d9d6122); /* 35 */
        HH(b, c, d, a, data[14], S34, 0xfde5380c); /* 36 */
        HH(a, b, c, d, data[1], S31, 0xa4beea44); /* 37 */
        HH(d, a, b, c, data[4], S32, 0x4bdecfa9); /* 38 */
        HH(c, d, a, b, data[7], S33, 0xf6bb4b60); /* 39 */
        HH(b, c, d, a, data[10], S34, 0xbebfbc70); /* 40 */
        HH(a, b, c, d, data[13], S31, 0x289b7ec6); /* 41 */
        HH(d, a, b, c, data[0], S32, 0xeaa127fa); /* 42 */
        HH(c, d, a, b, data[3], S33, 0xd4ef3085); /* 43 */
        HH(b, c, d, a, data[6], S34, 0x4881d05); /* 44 */
        HH(a, b, c, d, data[9], S31, 0xd9d4d039); /* 45 */
        HH(d, a, b, c, data[12], S32, 0xe6db99e5); /* 46 */
        HH(c, d, a, b, data[15], S33, 0x1fa27cf8); /* 47 */
        HH(b, c, d, a, data[2], S34, 0xc4ac5665); /* 48 */

        /* Round 4 */
        II(a, b, c, d, data[0], S41, 0xf4292244); /* 49 */
        II(d, a, b, c, data[7], S42, 0x432aff97); /* 50 */
        II(c, d, a, b, data[14], S43, 0xab9423a7); /* 51 */
        II(b, c, d, a, data[5], S44, 0xfc93a039); /* 52 */
        II(a, b, c, d, data[12], S41, 0x655b59c3); /* 53 */
        II(d, a, b, c, data[3], S42, 0x8f0ccc92); /* 54 */
        II(c, d, a, b, data[10], S43, 0xffeff47d); /* 55 */
        II(b, c, d, a, data[1], S44, 0x85845dd1); /* 56 */
        II(a, b, c, d, data[8], S41, 0x6fa87e4f); /* 57 */
        II(d, a, b, c, data[15], S42, 0xfe2ce6e0); /* 58 */
        II(c, d, a, b, data[6], S43, 0xa3014314); /* 59 */
        II(b, c, d, a, data[13], S44, 0x4e0811a1); /* 60 */
        II(a, b, c, d, data[4], S41, 0xf7537e82); /* 61 */
        II(d, a, b, c, data[11], S42, 0xbd3af235); /* 62 */
        II(c, d, a, b, data[2], S43, 0x2ad7d2bb); /* 63 */
        II(b, c, d, a, data[9], S44, 0xeb86d391); /* 64 */

        _state[0] += a;
        _state[1] += b;
        _state[2] += c;
        _state[3] += d;
    }
}
```

**chash.hpp**

```
#pragma once
#include "chash/IAlgorithm.hpp"

#if defined(_WIN32) || defined(_WIN64)
#ifdef __CHASH_EXPORTS__
#define CHASH_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define CHASH_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
#else
#define CHASH_API
#endif

namespace chash {
    CHASH_API IAlgorithm* createAlgorithm(EAlgorithm algorithm);

    template<EAlgorithm Algo>
    class TAlgorithm : public IAlgorithm {
    public:
        TAlgorithm() : IAlgorithm(EAlgorithm::Unknown) {
            algorithm = createAlgorithm(Algo);
            setType(Algo);
        }

        TAlgorithm(const TAlgorithm<Algo>&) = delete;
        TAlgorithm(TAlgorithm<Algo>&& other) 
            : algorithm(other.algorithm)
        {
        }

        ~TAlgorithm() {
            if (algorithm) {
                delete algorithm;
            }
        }

    private:
        IAlgorithm* algorithm;

    public:
        inline operator bool() const {
            return algorithm;
        }

        inline bool operator !() const {
            return !algorithm;
        }

        inline TAlgorithm<Algo>& operator =(const TAlgorithm<Algo>&) = delete;
        inline TAlgorithm<Algo>& operator =(TAlgorithm<Algo>&& other) {
            if (this != &other) 
                std::swap(algorithm, other.algorithm);

            return *this;
        }
        
    public:
        /* initiate the algorithm. */
        virtual bool init() override {
            if (algorithm) {
                bool retVal = algorithm->init();

                setError(algorithm->error());
                return retVal;
            }

            setError(EAlgorithmErrno::InvalidAlgorithm);
            return false;
        }

        /* update the algorithm state by given bytes. */
        virtual bool update(const uint8_t* inBytes, size_t inSize) override {
            if (algorithm) {
                bool retVal = algorithm->update(inBytes, inSize);

                setError(algorithm->error());
                return retVal;
            }

            setError(EAlgorithmErrno::InvalidAlgorithm);
            return false;
        }

        /* finalize the algorithm and digest. */
        virtual bool finalize(CDigest& outDigest) override {
            if (algorithm) {
                bool retVal = algorithm->finalize(outDigest);

                setError(algorithm->error());
                return retVal;
            }

            setError(EAlgorithmErrno::InvalidAlgorithm);
            return false;
        }
    };
}
```

**chash.cpp**

```
#include "chash.hpp"

#include "crc/CCRC16.hpp"
#include "crc/CCRC32.hpp"
#include "crc/CCRC64.hpp"

#include "md/CMD5.hpp"
#include "md/CMD4.hpp"

#include "sha/CSHA256.hpp"
#include "sha/CSHA384.hpp"
#include "sha/CSHA512.hpp"

#include "ripemd/CRipeMD128.hpp"
#include "ripemd/CRipeMD160.hpp"

namespace chash {
    CHASH_API IAlgorithm* createAlgorithm(EAlgorithm algorithm) {
        switch (algorithm) {
        case EAlgorithm::CRC16:
            return new CCRC16();

        case EAlgorithm::CRC32:
            return new CCRC32();

        case EAlgorithm::CRC64:
            return new CCRC64();

        case EAlgorithm::SHA256:
            return new CSHA256();

        case EAlgorithm::SHA384:
            return new CSHA384();

        case EAlgorithm::SHA512:
            return new CSHA512();

        case EAlgorithm::MD5:
            return new CMD5();

        case EAlgorithm::MD4:
            return new CMD4();

        case EAlgorithm::RipeMD128:
            return new CRipeMD128();

        case EAlgorithm::RipeMD160:
            return new CRipeMD160();
        }

        return nullptr;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
int main() {
    TAlgorithm<EAlgorithm::MD4> MD4;

    CDigest Digest;

    if (MD4.init()) {
        MD4.update((uint8_t*)"abcd", 4);
        MD4.finalize(Digest);

        printf("MD4(abcd): %s\n", toHex(Digest).c_str());
        return 0;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Comment: I don't have much to add to the fine reviews, but I'd make sure that your comparators are time-constant. This is a security requirement for some usages of hash algorithms and certainly HMAC.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I have implemented HMAC and pushed through github now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Keep it simple

I think you are focusing too much on creating a generic framework, and you lost sight of how you actually want to use your hash functions. As a *user* of your library, I just want to calculate the hash of some blob of data, I don't want to be bothered with what kind of class hierarchy you use. I don't want to write this line:

```
TAlgorithm<EAlgorithm::MD4> MD4;
```

Instead I want to write this line:

```
CMD4 MD4;
```

It gives me exactly what I want, with less typing and without the overhead of dynamically allocation. There is no reason at all to use the template `TAlgorithm`.

## Run-time algorithm selection

In most cases, you know which hash function you need, so you can immediately use the class that actually implements it. And in this case, you don't need those classes to inherit from `IAlgorithm` at all. The only time it is necessary is if you don't know at compile-time what algorithm to use, but when that is something you only know at run-time. In the latter case, I need a function to instantiate an object of the right type for me, and then I would want to write something like:

```
EAlgorithm algo = ...; // determined at run-time
auto hash = createAlgorithm(algo_name);

hash.update(...);
auto digest = hash.finalize();
```

## Use `std::unique_ptr` to manage resources

Avoid raw `new` and `delete` in your code, and prefer to use some type that makes resource management automatic, like [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr). For example, `createAlgorithm()` should return a `std::unique_ptr<IAlgorithm>`.

## Don't overload operators for `std::vector`

The class `CDigest` is now just an alias for `std::vector<uint8_t>`. The latter already has [operator overloads](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_cmp) that do exactly what you want, so don't reimplement them.

## Prevent being able to instantiate an invalid `IAlgorithm`

Your constructor for `TAlgorithm()` allows creating an instance with an "Unknown" algorithm:

```
TAlgorithm() : IAlgorithm(EAlgorithm::Unknown) {
     algorithm = createAlgorithm(Algo);
     setType(Algo);
}
```

If `createAlgorithm()` fails, it returns a `nullptr`. Now all the public functions have to check whether `algorithm` is a valid pointer, and propagate an error if it is `nullptr`.

It is much better to report errors as early as possible. I would just `throw` a [`std::runtime_error`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/runtime_error) inside `createAlgorithm()`, instead of returning a `nullptr`. This in turn will cause the constructor of `TAlgorithm` to throw an error. This way, you always know that if you have an instance of `TAlgorithm`, its member variable `algorithm` is pointing to a valid algorithm, and you no longer need the error checking in the other member functions.

Also, once you have that in place, you will note that there is no way `init()`, `update()` and `finalize()` can fail, so there is no need to return a `bool` indicating an error, and in fact you can have `finalize()` just `return` a `CDigest` instead of taking a reference to it as an output parameter.

## Use the constructor to initialize instead of an `init()` function

In C++ it is custom to use the constructor to ensure an object is properly initialized. This avoids the need to manually call an `init()` function. If you do want to have a separate `init()` function, then at least make sure you call this function from the constructor. In `class CMD5` for example, you don't, so the following code:

```
CMD5 hash;
hash.update("test", 4);
auto digest = hash.finalize();
```

Will result in a different digest than if you do:

```
CMD5 hash;
hash.init();
hash.update("test", 4);
auto digest = hash.finalize(digest);
```

But it's hard to spot the mistake; there is no compile-time or run-time error generated, and C++ programmers typically expect objects that have just been constructed to be in a good state.

## Avoid using pre-processor macros

You are using pre-processor macros in `CMD5.cpp`. Perhaps you copied the code from an open source C implementation? If so, ensure there is proper attribution and that the license is in fact compatible with your project. In this case, there is an argument to be made for leaving the code as it is, however if you wrote this code yourself, then I would try to replace the macros with proper functions. For example, instead of:

```
#define ROTATE_LEFT(x, n) (((x) << (n)) | ((x) >> (32-(n))))
```

Write:

```
static uint32_t ROTATE_LEFT(uint32_t x, uint32_t n) {
    return (x << n) | (x >> (32 - n));
}
```

Once you converted all the macros to functions and verified everything still works OK, you can search and replace all the function names with their lower case equivalents to signal that these are no longer macros.

## Use default member initialization if possible

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36600187/whats-the-differences-between-member-initializer-list-and-default-member-initia) for more details. But in short, using this often avoids the need to write a constructor, and it especially helps if you have multiple constructors for a class.

Comment: Thank you so much, and I've modified following your review!

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to create a new Code Review post with your modified code!

Answer (score 5):

### General Observations

Nice job. I think it was a good decision to create the `chash` namespace, although I might have used `CHash` instead of `chash`.

A lot of this code looks a lot more like the C programming language that the C++ programming language. Prefer `std::cout` instead of `printf()`. When using standard C header files, instead of `#include <stdint.h>` use `#include <cstdint>`, all of the standard C header files are prefaced with `c` in C++.

### Example Usage

The `main()` function provided does not include any `#include` statements or `using namespace chash;` statements, however, in Visual Studio 2019 professional it doesn't compile without these.

For the [same reason that `using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) is discouraged a `using namespace ...;` statement should be discouraged. It is much more helpful for people performing maintenance on the code if they know where a class, method, function or variable is coming from. I therefore recommend that the example be re-written as:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "chash.hpp"

int main()
{
    chash::TAlgorithm<chash::EAlgorithm::MD4> MD4;

    chash::CDigest Digest;

    if (MD4.init()) {
        MD4.update((uint8_t*)"abcd", 4);
        MD4.finalize(Digest);

        std::cout << "MD4(abcd): " << chash::toHex(Digest) << "\n";
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }

    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

In most C++ compilers on most operating systems `main()` should return 0 for success or 1 for failure, this example is using `-1` for failure. Rather than hard code numbers use the system defined symbolic constants [EXIT_SUCCESS and EXIT_FAILURE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8867871/should-i-return-exit-success-or-0-from-main) that are supplied in the C standard header file `cstdlib` (stdlib.h).

*Note, by replacing printf() with std::cout the statement is simplified because std::string::c_str does not need to be access, std::string has an override for the operator `<<`.*

### Macros.h

This header file is essentially a wrapper for `stdint.h`, it would be better to just `#include <cstdint>` anywhere that Macros.h is currently included.

### Obsolete Usage

For modern C++ compilers the keyword `inline` provides only a recommendation to the compiler to inline the function, thus rendering the keyword `inline` obsolete. When C++ is compiled with the optimization flag -O3 the compiler itself will decided whether a function should be in lined or not based on several factors.

### Prefer C++ Constants, Lambda Functions and Member Functions Over `#define` Macros

The use of C type macros is discouraged in C++, one of the reasons being that macros are not type safe, another is that multi-line macros are very hard to debug. There are several C++ constructs to replace macros, the original was the `inline` function, however, Lambda Functions or Expressions, regular functions and C++ style constants have all been created to replace the C style macro definition in C++, and these are all type safe.

In the file `CMD5.cpp` the first 46 lines of code contains more than 40 lines of macro definitions, these should be replaced with more modern C++ constructs.

```
static const int S11 = 7; // or unsigned, size_t, uint8_t etc. rather than int.
```

The macro ROTATE_LEFT could be defined as a private function in the class `CMD5`.

It isn't clear what the macros `F()`, `G()`, `H()`, and `I()` are doing so meaningful names might be better, the same could possibly be said for the macros `FF()`, `GG()`, `HH()` and `II()`.

### Common Programming Conventions

This isn't a rule, but it is generally followed, since most code is written by teams of developers, in class declarations put public variables and methods at the top so that they can be easily found by other members of the team using the code. It is better to have one public block and one private block (at least in C++).

### One Variable Declaration Per Line with Initialization

In both the C programming language and the C++ programming language it is best to initialize local variables when they are declared. To ease modification (maintain the code) each declaration and initialization should be on one line.

Let's say that I need to modify the second line of this code from `CMD5.cpp`:

```
    void CMD5::transform(const uint32_t* data) {
        uint32_t a = _state[0], b = _state[1], c = _state[2], d = _state[3];
```

It is going to be more difficult to add or remove a declaration than if the code looked like this:

```
    void CMD5::transform(const uint32_t* data) {
        uint32_t a = _state[0];
        uint32_t b = _state[1];
        uint32_t c = _state[2];
        uint32_t d = _state[3];
```